# regex contains "times" but not "clock"

Tags: python, regex

**Disclaimer:** I know "in" and "not in" can be used but due to technical contraints I need to use regex.

I have:

```
a = "digital clock time fan. Segments featuring digital 24 hour oclock times. For 11+"
b = "nine times ten is ninety"
```

and I would like to match based on contains "times" but not "oclock", so a and b are put through regex and only b passes

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
^(?!.*\bo?clock\b).*\btimes\b
```

Explanation:

```
^                 # starting at the beginning of the string
(?!               # fail if
   .*\bo?clock\b    # we can match 'clock' or 'oclock' anywhere in the string
)                 # end if
.*\btimes\b       # match 'times' anywhere in the string
```

The `\b` is for word boundaries, so you would still match a string like `'clocked times'` but would fail for a string like `'timeshare'`.  You can just remove all of the `\b` in the regex if you don't want this behavior.

Example:

```
>>> re.match(r'^(?!.*\bo?clock\b).*\btimes\b', a)
>>> re.match(r'^(?!.*\bo?clock\b).*\btimes\b', b)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fc1f96cc718>
```

Comment: Works in Java too (I saw the question tagged with "python")